# Create Loading To Wait Execution of Specific Code Until Finish Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game now. I have also make a save game and load game.
What i want is when i load the game (this mean code to load) i will show loading progress until code load execution is finish.

For example (LoadGame.cs):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Load_Timer_Merchant : MonoBehaviour {
    CloudSaver CloudSave;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        CloudSave = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CloudSave").GetComponent<CloudSaver>();

        CloudSave.Load_Timer_Merchant ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

I want to make the progress loading of that file script LoadGame.cs

Is that possible to do it ?

Thanks

Dennnis

Answer (score 0):

You have required [Co-routine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) to do this task
For instance, You want to log successful text as image load from a url something like this

```
 IEnumerator DoImageLoad()
{
    WWW txTexture = new WWW(m_szTexturePath);
    yield return txTexture;
    renderer.material.mainTexture = txTexture.texture;
    Debug.Log("Image Loaded. This message will show as image loaded");
}
     Start(){
     StartCoroutine("DoImageLoad");
     }
```

Comment: Hi Faizan, What i mean is something like Application.LoadLevelAsync. If we use this we can make percentase of loading. But that's just for change the level scene. So What about Load Game, and wait until all the game is loaded ?

Comment: that's mean that how we can know how much time it take to execute the script above. So i can make the progress loading to wait..

Comment: I am still confuse with the question. what do you mean by script load?

Comment: What i mean is, I have a script named LoadGame.cs and What i want is when the script LoadGame.cs is execute we could know how much time is take to execute all the LoadGame.cs file. It is mean too we can show a loading progress or loading bar when LoadGame.cs is being execute until the script LoadGame.cs execute is finish.